# Comparing user sign up info in an array with user login input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two buttons: a sign up and a log in. I intend to collect the input form values from the sign up into an array (this works). I then want to compare the user input from the sign up with the user input from the login and notify the user that they are logged in. (I am yet to get started with localStorage and JSON. I want to get this done using arrays first).

I have tried using a for loop and if statements with logical operators (&&).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#userSignUp").click(function() {
$("#signUpForm").show();
$("#signup").hide();
});
$("#userInfo").click(function(event) {

    var custName = $("#newName").val();
    var custEmail = $("#newEmail").val();
    var custPass = $("#newPass").val();
    var custData = [];
    custData.push(custName, custEmail, custPass);
    $("#userSignUp").text("Thank you for signing up!");
});
$("#userLogIn").click(function() {
    $("#loginForm").show();
    $("#login").hide();
});
$("#userData").click(function(event) {
    var currentName = $("#userName").val();
    var currentEmail = $("#userEmail").val();
    var currentPass = $("#userPass").val();
    for (var i = 0; i < custData.length; i++) {
  if ((currentName === custData[0]) && currentEmail === custData[1] && currentPass === custData[2]) {
            $("#userLogIn").text("You are logged in!");
        } else {
            $("#userLogIn").text("Please enter correct name, email and password!");
       }
    };
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try only IF statement without the loop.
The following thing checks if there is such item in the array and if it IS, will do smth:

```
if (custData.indexOf(currentName) != -1 
   && custData.indexOf(currentEmail) != -1 
   && custData.indexOf(currentPass) != -1) {
$("#userLogIn").text("You are logged in!");
} else {
$("#userLogIn").text("Please enter correct name, email and password!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been learning about localStorage. I decided to use it on this task. I collected the values that the user inputs when signing up, and 'saved' them on local Storage. I then collected the value the user inputs and 'retrieved' them via local Storage. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#userSignUp").click(function() {
  $("#signUpForm").show();
    $("#signup").hide();
 });
$("#userInfo").click(function(event) {
 var custName = $("#newName").val();
 var custEmail = $("#newEmail").val();
 var custPass = $("#newPass").val();
 localStorage.setItem("name", "Raych") +
 localStorage.setItem("email", "raych@gmail.com") +
 localStorage.setItem("password", "hey");   ;
 $("#userSignUp").text("Thank you for signing up!");
});
$("#userLogIn").click(function() {
 $("#loginForm").show();
 $("#login").hide();
});
$("#userData").click(function(event) {
 event.PreventDefault;
 var currentName = $("#userName").val();
 var currentEmail = $("#userEmail").val();
 var currentPass = $("#userPass").val();
 localStorage.getItem("name") +
 localStorage.getItem("email") +
 localStorage.getItem("password");      
 $("#userLogIn").text("You are logged in!");
 });
});
```